# What piano piece is Emil Nekola skating to in his short program?

Tags: music, yuri-on-ice

In episode 8 of *Yuri!!! on Ice*, Emil Nekola skates his short program to a piano piece. (This is around the eight-minute mark in the episode.) The music sounded like a classical work that I have heard before, but I was unable to place it. The most I have been able to gather is that if this is indeed a classical composition, it would have to be from the Romantic period in music at the earliest. (I also have a sense of which composers *wouldn't* have written something like this, but that's less useful.)

Is the music in Emil's short program an original composition? If not, what is its title and composer?

Comment: It seems silly that I figured this out pretty quickly after throwing out my earlier guesses for the piano piece and guessing that it was Mussorgsky, but since I didn't see anyone discuss the section of the soundtrack when I ran some preliminary searches, and since I couldn't find any useful Google results for `"yuri!!! on ice" "mussorgsky"` once I'd located my answer, I'll leave this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer after some additional guesswork and checking with some music recordings.

The piano music is an excerpt from Modest Mussorgsky's [*Pictures at an Exhibition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictures_at_an_Exhibition), specifically ["The Hut on Hen's Legs"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCELgdIadqs) section. The soundtrack before the episode cuts away to the end of Emil's performance clearly matches this; the piano music starts where this section of *Pictures at an Exhibition* begins and follows it (before the cut) without any alterations.